# Select By Time And Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have a table with Date Time Column

```
id      name          date_time
1       test      2015-12-10 22:00
1       test2     2015-12-20 20:00
1       test3     2015-12-13 05:00
1       test4     2015-12-15 11:00
```

I need write a select where date_time > 28 h from my date 
For Example we put 2015-12-15 12:00 , 
the result shown :

```
id      name          date_time
1       test      2015-12-10 22:00
1       test3     2015-12-13 05:00
```

Comment: `where date_time <= now() - interval 28 hour`

Comment: Was there a *question*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear what you're asking. First, because there is no question. SEcond, because you said you want date_times greater than 28 hours from your data, so why isn't '2015-12-20' included? Your expected results don't match up.

Comment: why negative Point ??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e783/1

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE date_time <= TIMESTAMP('2015-12-15 12:00') - INTERVAL 28 HOUR
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a small explanation along with the code makes for better answers.

Comment: I see almost nothing to comment. This is very simple query, but it is little bigger than @MarcB comment, and include fiddle with proof that it works using data provided inOP.

Comment: thank you Alex ... this is resolve my problem  ;)